# What is the initial thing in django?

Tags: django

I django, I can access the value of a field in a ModelForm by using the "initial" keyword.

I have no idea why, or what it is. Is it only used for accessing the value when i want to initialise it? Are there times when I cannot use the "initial" keyword?

I guess I'm asking this because 'initial' implies, well, initialising a value.

Apparently after calling "save" on a form I cannot change any values - but does that mean I can use "initial" willy nilly before then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should help:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

It's a place to stick initial field values that you want the fields populated with when the page loads.  You probably want to put things into initial during a get, and not mess with it during a post.

Comment: perfect, thanks. Also, what do i do if i want to edit the *bound* data?

Comment: You're likely wanting to edit that during a post handler, just before saving to the database. [This whole section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#using-validation-in-practice) is on validation.  Specifically, check out the sections about cleaning [a specific field attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) and [fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other). This work happens in the Form object.

Comment: ... after which it is available in [Form.cleaned_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data).